# почему выводит ошибку No such file or directory в PS?

Tags: python, powershell

столкнулся с такой проблемой: при запуске python файла в powershell выводит ошибку `C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.`

написанная мной команда:

```
PS C:\> python test.py
```

полный путь к файлу test.py:

C:\Users\alexa.atom\code_projects\test.py

очень бы хотелось увидеть развернутый ответ, заранее спасибо!

Comment: А чего вы хотите? Вы находитесь в корневой директории диска С:. В текущей директории файла test.py нет, но вы запускаете его без указания пути. Что вам мешает написать `python C:\Users\alexa.atom\code_projects\test.py` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых файл `test.py` не существует в диске С. Во вторых дефолтный путь Powershell-а `C:`. И python ищет файл в каталоге C. Можно так:
`python Users\alexa.atom\code_projects\test.py` или

```
cd Users\alexa.atom\code_projects
python test.py
```

Написав `cd Users\alexa.atom\code_projects` у тебя измениться путь Powershell на `C:\Users\alexa.atom\code_projects`. И Можно написать `python test.py`

Answer (score 2):

Вы запускаете команду находясь в папке `C:\`
Сначала перейдите в папку с файлом используя `cd C:\Users\alexa.atom\code_projects`